# MS Projects show task always in timesheet

Tags: sharepoint, task, ms-office, office-addins, ms-project

I am currently using microsoft projects 2016 with timesheets.
How can i create a task which is always shown in my timesheet with 0 planned work time?
I have administrative tasks beside my project tasks which i can't plan on an explicite date.
I have already tried to do this with an administrative time categorie, but this is shown for every user.
Is this currently supported? 
How could i implement this feature by myself throug an addon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround for this. You can create a task with any duration (for example from 01.10.2016 to 31.12.2100) and with a total work amount of 0.1 hours. Projects will plan 0 hours every day for this duration and the task is always shown in your timesheet.

Creating the task:

[image: Creating the task]

Appears in your timesheet:

[image: Timesheet]